MySQL trigger privileges
I just attempted an update on my Joomla 4 site.
When I attempted to run the database update I got this message:
CiviCRM 5.77.0 requires MySQL trigger privileges.
I was somewhere in the 5.7x range prior to the update, not completely up to date but not far behind either.
I've had this site with joomla+Civi for years and never had a problem with updating.
I'm on Mysqli 8.0.34-cll-lve  so I don't think that's the issue.
What would cause this?

It runs these two queries so you could try running the following using cv and see if it shows a useful error:
cv ev -vvv '(new CRM_Core_DAO())->query("CREATE TRIGGER civicrm_domain_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON civicrm_domain FOR EACH ROW BEGIN END");'
cv ev -vvv '(new CRM_Core_DAO())->query("DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS civicrm_domain_trigger");'
or alternatively add some debugging to see the details of the exception at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/1015f65a6391f1e8c82b9c9b69407e9190a14c3f/CRM/Core/DAO.php#L2560 and then try the upgrade again.

Thank you, I just also want to confirm that I do have the trigger privlege.

Applying the patch then gave some additional information, which ultimately required adjustig the MySQL config. Then it all worked.
